# Application defined or Object defined Error in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing following lines of code in the click event of the button which is on `Sheet2`. But this gives me `Object Defined or Application Defined` error. If I remove `Worksheets("Sheet1")` then it will work correctly but it selects `Sheet2's` range. I want the range from `Sheet1`.

So please help me with this.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, 5)).Sort _
Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlDescending
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `Cells` are not fully defined.

Try this

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 5)).Sort _
    Key1:=.Range("E2"), Order1:=xlDescending
End With
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem with VBA, and I would like to share my solution with you, here is my code:

```
Range("F76").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
.Merge
.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
With .Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data"
End With
End With
```

This fragment caused me trouble. Cell was defined properly (earlier in the code was fragment with sheet activate).

The solution includes only one line of code, I just needed to add

```
.Clear
```

to the code and everything worked again. I hope this will help someone.

Comment: If this is truly relevant to the question, can you explain how to solve the OP's issue rather than your own (possibly unrelated) issue?

Answer (score -3):

The solution above surely sovles the problem.
But simply adding a single row at the top will also work fine.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").activate
```